# Assign ranks to objects by values in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash, ranking

I have an array of objects like so:

```
var data = {
    a: [
        { keyone:'c', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 21, keyfour: 15 },
        { keyone:'a', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 22, keyfour: 15 },
        { keyone:'s', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 10, keyfour: 15 },
        { keyone:'v', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 7, keyfour: 15 }
    ],

    b: [
        { keyone:'f', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 45, keyfour: 100 },
        { keyone:'b', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 146, keyfour: 100 },
        { keyone:'t', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 23, keyfour: 100 },
        { keyone:'h', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 11, keyfour: 100 }
    ]
  };
```

I want to assign ranks to each object, based on values of `keythree` and `keyfour`, within the groups as well as within the entire data set. How would I do it?

Update: I have depicted the ranks in my code above.

Resultant object:

```
var data = {
    a: [
        { keyone:'c', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 21, keyfour: 15, rankgroup: 3, rankall: 4 },

        { keyone:'a', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 22, keyfour: 15, rankgroup: 4, rankall: 5 },

        { keyone:'s', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 22, keyfour: 15, rankgroup: 2, rankall: 2 },

        { keyone:'v', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 7, keyfour: 15, rankgroup: 1, rankall: 1 }
    ],

    b: [
        { keyone:'f', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 45, keyfour: 100 },

        { keyone:'b', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 146, keyfour: 100 },

        { keyone:'t', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 23, keyfour: 100 },

        { keyone:'h', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 11, keyfour: 100 }
    ]
};
```

I am using `lodash`. My idea is to first sort the array based on those keys, then loop over the original object, insert the sorted index by comparing another key. This is what I have tried:

```
var keys = Object.keys(data);
var result = {};
var numkeys;
for(var i=0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if(!numkeys) {
        var numkeys = _.keys(_.pick(data[keys[i]][0], _.isNumber));
  }

        for(var j=0;j<numkeys.length;j++) {
    var sorted = _.sortBy(data['a'], numkeys[j]);
        _.forEach(sorted, function(n, k) {

        //THIS FAILS
        var t = _.set(_.where(data[keys[i]], {keyone: n.keyone}), keys[i]+'rank', k);
        console.log(t);
        });

    }
  }
```

How would I do it? My logic seems too complex and the `set` method does not update the original object by key but adds a new entry after the main object.

**Update**: Notice the duplicate occurrence of `22` for the object `a`. This leads to an issue when assigning ranks, since `indexOf` will always return the index of the first occurrence, hence the second occurrence will never have an index assigned to it and hence the value will be undefined.

Comment: what do you mean with *as within the entire data set*? do you mean `a` and `b` or within `a` and `b`?

Comment: The ranking should be done for each subarray, meaning a and be, and it should be done w.r.t. to the entire list of array of objects. I'll update my description to add this fact.

Comment: please add an example of the sorted array.

Comment: I don't want to sort it, sorting will make me lose the original indexes. I want to calculate the ranks. I will post a resultant array with the ranks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how I achieved it.

1. collect all `keythree` into an array and sort them (to assign `rankall` based on `index`).

   ```
   var all = [];
   _.forEach(data, function (a, key) {
       _.forEach(a, function(n, k){
       all.push(n.keythree);
     });
   });
   all.sort(function(a,b){
       return a-b;
   });
   ```
2. assign ranks

   ```
   _.forEach(data, function (a, key) {
       var sorted = _.sortBy(a, 'keythree');
       _.forEach(sorted, function(n, k) {
         var index = _.findIndex(data[key], {keyone: n.keyone});
         data[key][index]['rankgroup'] = k+1;
         data[key][index]['rankall'] = all.indexOf(n.keythree)+1;
       });
   });
   ```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/1150/)

---

#### EDIT

i'm creating another array for dupes

```
_.forEach(a, function(n, k) {
    if (all.indexOf(n.keythree) !== -1) {
        dupes.push(n.keythree);
    }
    all.push(n.keythree);
});
```

and for getting the global rank for these dupe items

```
    function getGlobalRank(n) {
    var val = n.keythree;
    if (sorted_dupes[val] === undefined) {
        sorted_dupes[val] = [];
        _.forEach(data, function(a, key) {
            _.forEach(_.where(a, {
                keythree: val
            }), function(b) {
                sorted_dupes[val].push(b);
            });
        });
        sorted_dupes[val] = _.sortByAll(sorted_dupes[val], ['keyfour', 'keytwo', 'keyone']);
    }
    return _.findIndex(sorted_dupes[val], {
        keyone: n.keyone,
        keytwo: n.keytwo,
        keythree: n.keythree,
        keyfour: n.keyfour
    }) + 1 + all.indexOf(val);
}
```

see that the items are sorted based on all the properties in the order `keythree`, `keyfour`, `keytwo`, `keyone` (you can change the order inside `_.sortByAll` if you want to)

the code looking uglier than i thought. will update the refactored code soon

check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/W4QfJ/1151/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! The fiddle looks perfect! Let me try this in my actual data!

Comment: How do I check for duplicates? I mean how will the ranking work for duplicate values? I am accepting your answer since I could understand and modify it to rank all the `numeric` values in my data set in a similar fashion.

Comment: pushing only non-duplicate values to `all` array results in 1) items being ranked correctly among their group, but 2) multiple items can be ranked same globally

Comment: Yes! I got to that while going through the code. Thanks again.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde did you check the updated answer? is it of any help?

Comment: I haven't tried this one, but I think a simple existence check while pushing to the `all` array should do it.

Comment: I want the same rank for duplicates. Which works if you insert it only once in the `all` array. But when duplicates exist in the same parent object, meaning `a` or `b`, then the index for the first value is available twice or as many times it repeats in the object. All the further occurrences will get the rank as `undefined`. Ex. If `keyOne: 1` exists twice in `a`, only the first one can be assigned a rank. The second one will be undefined.

Comment: does duplicates mean items with same `keythree` value?
how do you want to rank inter "duplicate" items(items from different category) and intra "duplicate" items(items from same category)?

Comment: What I mean is, if an array has an element, say `a` twice, indexOf will always return the index of the first element, unless I somehow keep a track of the first occurrence. Hence I used another criteria, which is guaranteed to be a unique value.

Answer (score 2):

Just in plain Javascript:

For ranking, the data must be sorted, somehow.

This solution features an array with objects and the references to the given objects in `data`. Then all items are sorted and the original data gets their `rankgroup` and `rankall` property.

Edit: Now with same rank for duplicates.

```js
var data = { a: [{ keyone: 'g', keytwo: 'tina', keythree: 21, keyfour: 15 }, { keyone: 'c', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 21, keyfour: 15 }, { keyone: 'a', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 22, keyfour: 15 }, { keyone: 's', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 10, keyfour: 15 }, { keyone: 'v', keytwo: 'anna', keythree: 7, keyfour: 15 }], b: [{ keyone: 'f', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 45, keyfour: 100 }, { keyone: 'b', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 146, keyfour: 100 }, { keyone: 't', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 23, keyfour: 100 }, { keyone: 'h', keytwo: 'any', keythree: 11, keyfour: 100 }] },
    group = {};

Object.keys(data).reduce(function (r, k) {
    return r.concat(data[k].map(function (a) {
        return { obj: k, ref: a };
    }));
}, []).sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.ref.keythree - b.ref.keythree || a.ref.keyfour - b.ref.keyfour;
}).forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    if (i && a.ref.keythree === aa[i - 1].ref.keythree && a.ref.keyfour === aa[i - 1].ref.keyfour) {
        a.ref.rankgroup = group[a.obj];
        a.ref.rankall = group.rankall;
    } else {
        group[a.obj] = (group[a.obj] || 0) + 1;
        group.rankall = (group.rankall || 0) + 1;
        a.ref.rankgroup = group[a.obj];
        a.ref.rankall = group.rankall;
    }
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying this one too.

Comment: Upvoting. I ended up using @Venugopal's solution since I could modify it for my purpose which involved ranking all the `numeric values` in my data.

Comment: you can just add more sorting groups to `return a.ref.keythree - b.ref.keythree || a.ref.keyfour - b.ref.keyfour` with `|| a.ref.keyfive - b.ref.keyfive`, and so on.

Comment: Aha. Let me try that.

Comment: How would you handle a situation with dupes in the same object? Dupes should get the same rank.

Comment: please see edit. i deletet the connection to i for the rank. the rank is now counted independently. same values get now the same rank.

Comment: Thanks! I will update the question. Your code looks better when formatted, I was initially scared of it ;)